# Adding generic extension methods to interfaces like IEnumerable

Tags: c#, generics, extension-methods

I've been trying and trying to make my generic extension methods work, but they just refuse to and I can't figure out **why**.
[This thread didn't help me, although it should.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618271/why-is-it-impossible-to-declare-extension-methods-in-a-generic-static-class)

Of course I've looked up how to, everywhere I see they say it's simple and it should be in this syntax:

(On some places I read that I need to add "where T: [type]" after the parameter decleration, but my VS2010 just says that's a syntax error.)

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;

public static class TExtensions
{
    public static List<T> ToList(this IEnumerable<T> collection)
    {
        return new List<T>(collection);
    }

    public static BindingList<T> ToBindingList(this IEnumerable<T> collection)
    {
        return new BindingList<T>(collection.ToList());
    }
}
```

But that just doesn't work, I get this error:

> The type or namespace name 'T' could
>   not be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)

If I then replace

```
public static class TExtensions
```

by

```
public static class TExtensions<T>
```

it gives this error:

> Extension method must be defined in a
>   non-generic static class

Any help will be much appreciated, I'm really stuck here.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think what you're missing is making the *methods* generic in `T`:

```
public static List<T> ToList<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection)
{
    return new List<T>(collection);
}

public static BindingList<T> ToBindingList<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection)
{
    return new BindingList<T>(collection.ToList());
}
```

Note the `<T>` after the name of each method, before the parameter list. That says it's a generic method with a single type parameter, `T`.

Comment: Oh god I knew it was something stupid like that. Thanks a bunch! Can't believe I missed that ><

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
public static class TExtensions
{
  public static List<T> ToList<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection)
  {
      return new List<T>(collection);
  }

  public static BindingList<T> ToBindingList<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection)
  {
      return new BindingList<T>(collection.ToList());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not actually created generic methods you have declared non geeneric methods that return `List<T>` without defining T.  You need to change as below:

```
public static class TExtensions
    {
        public static List<T> ToList<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection)
        {
            return new List<T>(collection);
        }

        public static BindingList<T> ToBindingList<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection)
        {
            return new BindingList<T>(collection.ToList());
        }
    }
```